# NameError while making a new Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nameerror

Im using Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.2.2 and RubyGems 1.6.2

A few hours before, I Installed all the requirements and then made a demo ruby on rails app using

```
rails demo
```

and then started the server and it worked fine!
After restarting my computer I tried to make a new app by

```
rails depot
```

it gave me the following error:-

```
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/basic_object.rb:22: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::BlankSlate (NameError)
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `gem_original_require'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support.rb:25
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `gem_original_require'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/bin/../lib/rails_generator.rb:28
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `gem_original_require'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/bin/rails:13
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/bin/rails:19:in `load'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/bin/rails:19
```

I tried to run the server from the demo app I made earlier, it too gave an error:-

```
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/basic_object.rb:22: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::BlankSlate (NameError)
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `gem_original_require'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support.rb:25
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `gem_original_require'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/server.rb:1
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `gem_original_require'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from script/server:3
```

Please help!

Comment: it should be `rails new demo` and `rails new depot`

Comment: I'm using rails 1.8.7 in which 
rails appname works fine, It worked fine with the demo app which I worked earlier.

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version of Rails?

Comment: @Iceman
Because the company I work for uses it!
In any case the error has nothing to do with the older Rails version!